# Linux GCC - Symbol could not resolved in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gnu

I have a source file '**foo.c**' which includes '**foo1.h**'  and '**foo2.c**'.

foo1.h

```
#include "pthread.h"

#define MACROFOO() PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
// Few other macros
```

foo2.h

```
#include "pthread.h"

#define MACROFOO() PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER
// Few other macros
```

foo.c

```
#include "foo1.h"
#include "foo2.h"

typedef struct mut
{
    pthread_mutex_t mut;
    int state;
}strMut;

strMut->mutex = MACROFOO();
```

When i compile foo.c file, compiler says that **MACROFOO** could not resolve. **MACROFOO** is declared in both foo1.h and foo2.h and i have included both the headers in foo.c

I have few other macros in these header files due to which i **HAVE** to include both the headers.

Here the magic is that when i right click on the MACROFOO in source file and press 'Go To Declaration', both the foo1.h and foo2.h are shown. So basically compiler knows where MACROFOO is declared.

I am using **Eclipse JUNO v1.5.1**.

I have tried to remove MACROFOO from one of the header files but problem still exists.(however i am not suppose to remove MACROFOO from any of the header file).

Any help ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Include the source code. 2. There is sth very bad with your code if you've got the same macro declared in two headers. It's even worse that those two headers are part of one compilation unit foo.c

Comment: Yes i understand the bad coding style but I am not suppose to edit the header. Let me paste my code.

Comment: is MACROFOO() undef'd at the end of the included headers? that's definitely something to check for.

Comment: yes MACROFOO is defined. Let me combine all the inputs and try. Thanks

Comment: Please exactly quote the compiler's error message.

Comment: `"pthread.h"` to `<pthread.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `#include <header.h>` is used to indicate a library headers, `#include "header.h"` is used for local, user-defined headers. `pthread.h` most likely refers to the POSIX thread library with the same name, and not a local header file in the project.

Change`#include "pthread.h"` to `#include <pthread.h>` and see if this solves the issue.

Also you should *always* use header guards to avoid various linker errors:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HEADER_H

/* the whole contents of the header file here */

#endif /* MY_HEADER_H */
```